# How far up should I build my floating city?

Tags: humans, cities

I'm designing a floating city in my world. Ignore the physics and hard science behind this. Assume that the humans living here will have adequate food, water, and shelter. How far up should I build this city for the safety and comfortability of the humans? Obviously the most comfortable altitude is on the ground, but in the air, what would be the best altitude? Also, I don't want Everest level heights where people need oxygen tanks to not die from oxygen deprivation.

**Edit:** The city should be at least 100 feet (about 30 meters) above the ground.

Comment: You agree the best height is on the ground, so do you have a lower limit? Why not just put it an inch above the ground?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh edited to clarify

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - somewhat below ground would be better lest it blow away in high winds.

Comment: How is my question unclear? I have two close votes.

Comment: Why a floating city?  It doesn't seem to make sense on Earth.  If you put a domed floating city on Venus, it would make more sense and there'd be more definite parameters for where it should be located.  Note:  if your reason is something like "it would be cool" then you can always ask a question for an in-universe reason to support that.  Of course, specifying acceptance criteria to avoid a Too Broad classification may be challenging.  That might make a good [Sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/635/2113) question.

Comment: @Brythan But the point is not if it makes sense. The question is only asking for an optimal altitude. That said, I could see this question being closed as too opinionated, but I just don't understand how this is unclear. I've stated the question: "How far up should I build this city for the safety and comfortability of the humans?"

Comment: And people already told you:  on the ground (with the foundation buried).  If we knew why the city was floating, then we could better give you different answers.  As it is, you haven't specified any acceptance criteria that would support an answer other than not floating.  Why must it be at least a hundred meters off the ground?  In-universe, not just because that's the story that you want to tell.

Comment: Well it depends on so many factors... What is the tech level of the rest of humanity (wrt flying/anti-air warfare)? How aggressive they are? Are you intending to trade? Are you intending to roam and if so, over what kind of landscape? Is city's movement controllable? Can you adjust height? Generally, I would suggest placing it as low as possible, but out of reach of current ground-based weapons, because living on an air island is cool and will make others jealous.

Answer (score 2):

best is relative to what people would like.  Being able to move up and down can make all the difference.

When it gets real hot, go up, it gets cooler as you go up.  Storms coming?  go over them.  Need more water, go under small rain showers.

It can also be influenced by the latitude that the city is floating at, and the season.  Kansas in May?  stay pretty high not to get caught in a tornado, Florida in August, stay above the hurricanes.

But to stay above the weather all the time would be a little cold and maybe hard to breath, so coming back down during nice weather is also good.

Comment: Also keep it higher in the summer, in order to enjoy cooler temperatures.